# Getting Latitude and Longitude from name of intersection point?

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude

For example, my intersection is Cross Avenue @ Sacramento Street, in the City of Tulare, CA.

I need a tool that gives me a GPS location for like 1500 intersections.

Comment: That is called Geocoding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding. Do you have addressed streets to look up? What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

## Using PostGIS

See [`geocode_intersection`](https://postgis.net/docs/Geocode_Intersection.html) in PostGIS for the open source method of doing this.

> **Geocode_Intersection** — Takes in 2 streets that intersect and a state, city, zip, and outputs a set of possible locations on the first cross street that is at the intersection, also includes a geomout as the point location in NAD 83 long lat, a normalized_address (addy) for each location, and the rating. The lower the rating the more likely the match. Results are sorted by lowest rating first. Can optionally pass in maximum results, defaults to 10. Uses Tiger data (edges, faces, addr), PostgreSQL fuzzy string matching (soundex, levenshtein).